# Getting the parameters of a running JVM

Tags: java, jvm

Is there a way to get the parameters of a running JVM?

Is there a command-line tool, like jstat, which takes as input the [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) of the JVM and returns its starting parameters? I am particularly interested in the *-Xmx* and *-Xms* values that were given when starting the JVM.

To clarify my constraints for the JVM, we would like to check if it is running on a production server. That's why we prefer the minimum disruption. We are able to monitor the JVM using jstat, and so we hope there's a similar simple solution to access the parameters.

We also tried to get the parameters using jvisualvm. But in order to connect to a remote jvm, we need to run jstatd and modify the security settings of the JVM, which we found to be very disruptive and risky on a production server.

Comment: You can find a tool there : [JDK Tools and Utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/index.html)

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You can use jps like:

```
jps -lvm
```

It prints something like:

```
4050 com.intellij.idea.Main -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -ea -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar -Djb.restart.code=88
4667 sun.tools.jps.Jps -lvm -Dapplication.home=/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_22 -Xms8m
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I also discovered the jinfo tool in the jdk which has a similar function

Comment: Notice that the output of `jps -lvm` might be misleading. Always double check with jinfo or other tool. The problem can be if "-XX" is passed like the normal program argument and ignored by JVM. This is the case if you use `java -jar my.jar -Xmx3g` instead of `java -Xmx3g -jar my.jar`

Answer (score 76):

As per [JDK 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr025.html) jcmd is the suggested approach.

> It is suggested to use the latest utility, jcmd instead of the
> previous jstack, jinfo, and jmap utilities for enhanced diagnostics
> and reduced performance overhead.

Below are commands to get your properties/flags you want.

```
jcmd pid VM.system_properties
jcmd pid VM.flags
```

We need the [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier). For this, use `jcmd -l`, like below

```
cd ~/javacode
jcmd -l

11441 Test
6294 Test
29197 jdk.jcmd/sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd -l
```

Now it is time to use these PIDs to get properties/flags you want.

Command: **jcmd 11441 VM.system_properties**

```
11441:
#Tue Oct 17 12:44:50 IST 2017
gopherProxySet=false
awt.toolkit=sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
java.specification.version=9
sun.cpu.isalist=
sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
java.class.path=.
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
sun.arch.data.model=64
java.vendor.url=http\://java.oracle.com/
user.timezone=Asia/Kolkata
java.vm.specification.version=9
os.name=Mac OS X
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
user.country=US
sun.boot.library.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib
sun.java.command=Test
http.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
jdk.debug=release
sun.cpu.endian=little
user.home=/Users/XXXX
user.language=en
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
file.separator=/
java.vm.compressedOopsMode=Zero based
line.separator=\n
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
ftp.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
java.runtime.version=9+181
user.name=XXXX
path.separator=\:
os.version=10.12.6
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
file.encoding=UTF-8
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vendor.url.bug=http\://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/
java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/dm/gd6lc90d0hg220lzw_m7krr00000gn/T/
java.version=9
user.dir=/Users/XXXX/javacode
os.arch=x86_64
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.awt.printerjob=sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob
sun.os.patch.level=unknown
MyParam=2
java.library.path=/Users/XXXX/Library/Java/Extensions\:/Library/Java/Extensions\:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions\:/System/Library/Java/Extensions\:/usr/lib/java\:.
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version=9+181
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig
java.class.version=53.0
socksNonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
```

Command: **jcmd 11441 VM.flags output:**

```
11441:
-XX:CICompilerCount=3 -XX:ConcGCThreads=1 -XX:G1ConcRefinementThreads=4 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=1048576 -XX:InitialHeapSize=67108864 -XX:MarkStackSize=4194304 -XX:MaxHeapSize=1073741824 -XX:MaxNewSize=643825664 -XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=1048576 -XX:NonNMethodCodeHeapSize=5830092 -XX:NonProfiledCodeHeapSize=122914074 -XX:ProfiledCodeHeapSize=122914074 -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=251658240 -XX:+SegmentedCodeCache -XX:-UseAOT -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseFastUnorderedTimeStamps -XX:+UseG1GC
```

For more instructions of usages of jcmd, see [my blog post](https://vipin-sharma.github.io/blog/JCMD).

Comment: Could not find any processes matching : 'pid'

Comment: pid should be replaced with java process id, Linux os generally we get it by “ps -ef | grep jdk” , if you see multiple processes by this then ask a new question or try to google it

Answer (score 41):

On Linux:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
```

On Mac OS X:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'heapsize|permsize|threadstacksize'
```

On Windows:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"
```

Source: *[Find out your Java heap memory size](https://www.mkyong.com/java/find-out-your-java-heap-memory-size/)*

Comment: This does not address the question which is to get JVM flags of a running process

Answer (score 31):

Alternatively, you can use [jinfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jinfo.html)

```
jinfo -flags <vmid> 
jinfo -sysprops <vmid>
```

Comment: This utility is unsupported and may or may not be available in future versions of the JDK.

Comment: `-flags` option does not exist in OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.8.0_111-internal-alpine-r0-b14) (current `java:8u111-jdk-alpine` Docker image)

Comment: I wrote this answer with Java 6/7 in mind. Beyond that jinfo is unreliable, but `flags` works with official Docker java image based on  Debian Jessie  `docker run --rm -it java:8u111-jdk java -version && jinfo -h`

Comment: Perhaps it is time for an update of the answer?

Answer (score 25):

If you can do this in Java, try:

[RuntimeMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html)

[ManagementFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html)

**Example:**

```
RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
List<String> jvmArgs = runtimeMXBean.getInputArguments();
for (String arg : jvmArgs) {
    System.out.println(arg);
}
```

Comment: Will only provide values if it was passed, hence no default settings.

Answer (score 19):

On Linux, you can run this command and see the result:

```
ps aux | grep "java"
```

Comment: My company uses Red Hat Linux and I have very limited access to the system. ps aux | grep "java" command lists all the java commands with their jvm arguments and we can even grep the exact jvm argument if needed. This is really useful in case any other tools such as jps, jcmd etc are not available/accessible.

Answer (score 12):

JConsole can do it. Also you can use the powerful [Java VisualVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualVM) tool, which also is included in JDK since 1.6.0.8.

Answer (score 5):

Windows 10 or [Windows Server 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2016) provide such information in their standard *[Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows))*.

It is a rare case for production, but if the target JVM is running on Windows, the simplest way to see its parameters is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, choose the **Processes** tab and add the **Command line** column (by clicking the right mouse button on any existing column header).

Answer (score 2):

In case of really small containers (no `ps`, `tree`, `jcmd` etc.) you can also try to guess process id (by listing `ls -l /proc`) and then read parameters from specific process:
`cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline`.

example:

`$ cat /proc/614/cmdline`

may print something like:

`java-D[Standalone]-server-Xms64m-Xmx512m-XX:MetaspaceSize=96M-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman-Djava.awt.headless=true-Dkeycloak.profile=preview-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=1800-Djboss.node.name=keycloak1loak/modulesorg.jboss.as.standalone`

To read the same for all processes (discarding any permission errors and processes that dissapeared during command execution):

`for i in $(find /proc/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -name cmdline -exec ls {} 2>/dev/null \; ); do echo "$i"; cat $i 2>/dev/null; echo; echo; done`

Note: It's not narrowed down to java processes only - you can do that using `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

This technique applies for any Java applications running local or remote.

1. Start your Java application.
2. Run [Java VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) found in you JDK (such as *C:\Program
   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\jvisualvm.exe*).
3. When this useful tool starts look at the list of running Java applications under the
   "Local" tree node.
4. Double click [your application] (pid [n]).
5. On the right side, there will be inspection contents in a tab for the
   application. In the middle of the *Overview* tab, you will see the JVM arguments for the application.

Java VisualVM can be found in any JDK since JDK 6 Update 7.  Video tutorial on Java VisualVM is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8n7Bg7-A4I).

Comment: OP explicitly stated that jvisualvm was not an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in getting the JVM parameters of a running Java process, then just do `kill -3 java-pid`.

You will get a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) file in which you can find the JVM parameters used while launching the Java application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JConsole command (or any other JMX client) to access that information.

Answer (score 0):

*_JAVA_OPTIONS* is an environment variable that can be expanded:

```
echo $_JAVA_OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do `ps -ef | grep java`. It outputs the process with PID + the used command line parameters.