# Java - Get JVM memory settings at runtime

Tags: java

I have a Java 7 program which launches other Java processes. I would like for memory settings for the original program to be passed along to the child processes.

The processes are launched as follows:

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636367/executing-a-java-application-in-a-separate-process
String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
String javaBin = javaHome + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
String className = MyClass.class.getCanonicalName();

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(javaBin, "-cp", classpath, "-Djava.ext.dirs=" + System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs"), className, arg1, arg2);
logger.debug("Running as {}", new Object[]{pb.command()});

pb.start();
```

The process works correctly, except in the cases where the program needs it's children to have additional memory.

I've iterated over `System.getProperties()` to look for any of the memory settings, but none seem present.

Specifically, the three memory configurations I need are `-Xms`, `-Xmx`, and `-XX:MaxPermSize`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the exact meaning of Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() and freeMemory()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory)

Comment: Would this help? [Getting the parameters of a running JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317152/getting-the-parameters-of-a-running-jvm)

Answer (score 2):

In order to get all JVM parameters including Xmx etc
You have to use

```
    java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
```

Following example lists all jvm parameters available :

```
  public void runtimeParameters() {

  RuntimeMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
  List<String> aList = bean.getInputArguments();
  for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {

   System.out.println(aList.get(i));

  } 

}
```