# Java runtime parameters in custom directory

Tags: java, jvm

I have a java installed in `C:\MyFolder\Test\bin\jvm` and in the windows console I can successfully check the version by doing `C:\MyFolder\Test\bin\jvm\bin\java.exe -version`.

My question is, how can I check all the VM options set? For example I want to know the value of -Xms or if `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` is currently set to true or false.

Comment: Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317152/getting-the-parameters-of-a-running-jvm

Comment: You set these VM options yourself on the command line. There is no global place where they are set, and the JVM itself does not remember such settings in a configuration file.

Comment: @Jesper so what information does  "java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal" give?

Comment: It prints a bunch of parameters that are set for that execution of the `java` command. If you really mean: "I want to know the current JVM settings from inside my running Java program", then see the answer that Thusita linked to above.

Comment: aha I see,also how can I verify that the current JVM supports a paramter ?

Comment: You may want to check this: https://chriswhocodes.com/hotspot_options_jdk8.html