# Finding Application Property Key Values from Running JVM process

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, groovy, jvm

I have a Grails application deployed on tomcat. However recently while cleaning up files on the server there was accidental deletion of the groovy config file. But the application is still working as it's loaded into JVm with the required config details.

Is there a way where I can extract the application property key values from the Running tomcat JVM process..Ex of key map.stage.threads

If I restart tomcat I cannot start it back as the app would not start back due to missing property file.

Note: There is no back up and there are some custom values for important keys as math calc based on that deployment.

Comment: Create a heap dump with `jmap`, then browse the contents of the dump with VisualVM or Eclipse Memory Analyzer.

Comment: Or use `rekall` to do a memory analysis, live or offline from a memory dump. You can first run `lsof | grep your_file` to check if the file is on memory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317152/getting-the-parameters-of-a-running-jvm should help

Comment: But i need to extract application property key and value which was read from config.groovy file. I don't need JVM sys keys.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your tricky problem, but you could try posting this issue on [the official Grails forum](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/). You'll have to register before posting.